# SQL delete large amounts of data

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-delete

I have been trying to de-dupe a table by relating an ID from table 2 to table 1.  I want to use the DELETE function but it keeps timing out (for whatever reason, the index, the large amount of data, etc.)  I know this can be done in a rather quick and easy fashion but I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
DELETE *
FROM `TABLE 1`
WHERE EXISTS (select *
              from table2
              where t2.Client_Code = t1.Client_Code and t2.`account#` = t1.`account#`
             );
```

So as you can see, I want to delete where table1's client code is = to table2's client code, table1's account# is = to table2's account# etc.  When I try and run this query, SQLYOG becomes stagnant and does not process.  I even let it try and do it's thing for a few hours and no progress.  Is there anything I can do to make this happen?  I see the admin run queries like this all the time with ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add an index over t2, on attributes Client_Code and account#. This may improve the selection on the inner query.

Comment: Before I was having trouble setting the index for my tables.  I was trying to set numbers/characters as unique or primary indexes.  I just needed to set them as neither and it worked.  That is exactly what I needed.